# Cucumber and TestNG integration

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, cucumber

I have a simple question as I am just getting into Test Automation.

I want to develop Cucumber smoke tests and acceptance tests as they would be easy to read and understand for my colleagues. Unfortunately, I am using TestNG and Cucumber is in Junit.

I am not interested in using Junit in my testing overall but I am okay with using for Cucumber acceptance/smoke tests but I don't have any practical experience with this. Would it be convoluted or difficult to use Junit just with Cucumber tests and TestNG with all of my other lower level tests ?

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber is not really driven by JUnit. [JUnit Runner](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#junit-runner) is an easy way to integrate running cucumber into an existing testing infrastructure (like `mvn verify`).

That one single empty JUnit Runner class should not give you much pain against TestNG. The only thing important for you is to plug it into a proper build lifecycle phase, we often use it on `integration-test` instead of the `test` phase instead of the maven.

Technically you could use something else instead of the JUnit to start cucumber tests, for example their [CLI runner](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#cli-runner) either from command line or programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cucumber with either JUnit or TestNG, if you want to run it from a test framework.
You can also run it directly from the command line, from your IDE or from a build tool like Maven or Gradle.

For an example using TestNG, have a look at: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/java-calculator-testng

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber-jvm is object oriented while TestNG is class oriented.  The two don't mesh well.  That being said, take a look at the following:

[automatictester](https://automatictester.co.uk/2015/06/11/basic-cucumberjvm-selenium-webdriver-test-automation-framework/)

[java-calculator-testng](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/java-calculator-testng)

[testng](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/testng)

The best option appears to be one TestNG test runner per feature file.